# Whether IBM Mobile First supports background Services?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to create a mobile app that alert me when I enter certain location even though the app is closed.To achieve this the app has to run in background.
I thought of doing it using IBM Mobile First.Before that I just want to clarify whether it supports background services or not?

Answer (score 1):

Despite that I never implement an background application the answer is yes as we can see in documentation of the product.

> You can add code at the beginning of the application lifecycle, before
>   the MobileFirst framework is initialized, and have full control over
>   when to initialize the MobileFirst framework, including being able to
>   initialize it in the background

[IBM Knowledge Center - Developing MobileFirst applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/topics/c_devwlapps.html)

See the explanation on how to do it on topic:

**Keeping the application running in the background**

> For Android devices and hybrid applications, to ensure that the
>   application will continue to run in the background use
>   WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(true, options).

[IBM Knowledge Center - Keeping the application running in the background](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_keeping_app_running_in_background.html)

Finally, specific informations about location services:
[MobileFirst Foundation DEV - Location services in hybrid applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-client-side-development/location-services-hybrid-applications)

Regards,
Bernardo Baumblatt.

Comment: Thank you Bernardo . Can you please provide me the installation steps of IBM Mobile First Studio 8.0 in eclpise mars ?

Comment: Hi Janaki, sorry, but I can't help you, I'd know only the MFP CLI.

Comment: Its Ok Bernardo.Can you please tell me how to add platforms ? (Whenever I register the app it says No platform were detected)

Comment: Hi Janaki, sorry, but I don't understand what it's happening! I suggest that you open another question with all informations about what you are trying to do! (steps and logs).